# I am getting some problem while login from jwt token, I can get token but getting some problem as authentication not provided ? In Django from API

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am getting some problems while logging the user. I can get proper tokens also but can't authenticate that.

[image]

I am Getting an Error as Below also while getting the token too.

[image]

```
HTTP 401 Unauthorized

Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS

Content-Type: application/json

Vary: Accept

WWW-Authenticate: JWT realm="api"
{

    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

**In setting.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'webapi.apps.WebapiConfig',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'ratings',
    # 'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
    'rest_auth',
    'phone_field',
    'phonenumber_field',
    'djoser',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {

    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,
    'JWK_URL': None,
    'LEEWAY': 0,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}
```

**At urls.py**

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
    TokenRefreshView,
    TokenVerifyView,
)

urlpatterns = [

    path('token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('token/verify/', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name='token_verify'),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Butterfly

if you are using postman you should not insert the token in **params** section.
[image]

what you should do is to enter the Bearer and the token in **headers** part in `postman` , then your code will work just fine.

[image]

if you are generating a custom token, be sure that the **token type** is `access` , the code would be like this:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

def get_tokens_for_user(user):
    token= RefreshToken.for_user(user)

    return {
        'refresh': str(token),
        'access': str(token.access_token),
    }
```

if you didnt get your answer check the documentation:
https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

You should include django session authentication

That's what django Rest framework default templates use.

Comment: Yeah thanks it works but while integrating with react I am getting some problems so can you help me please

Comment: Can I use Django session authentication and JWT authentication while integrating with reacts??

Comment: JWT alone is enough for your react frontend but to use the default DRF frontend you have in the picture, you need to include session auth.

Comment: When i include django session it works but I don't think JWT token is working.

Comment: DRF front-end doesn't use any other kind of auth except Basic or Session.

Comment: But your JWT auth will come into play if you test it using Postman. Send the token along the request.